# Unable to allocate pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, graph

I am making a graph using **Adjacency Matrix**.
This is my header file - **graph.h** -

```
typedef struct Node{
    int vertex;
}Node_t;

typedef Node_t *Row;

typedef struct graph_t{
    int noOfVertices;
    Row *rowPointer;
}graph_t, *graph_p;
```

This is my definition file - **graph.c** -

```
graph_p createGraph(int noOfVertices){
    int i,
        j;
    graph_p graph = (graph_p)malloc(sizeof(graph_t));

    graph->noOfVertices = noOfVertices;
    graph->rowPointer = (Row *)malloc(noOfVertices * sizeof(Row));
    fprintf(stdout, "\nValue of graph->rowPointer: %p\n", graph->rowPointer);

    for(i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++){
        Row r = (Node_t *)malloc(noOfVertices * sizeof(Node_t));
        fprintf(stdout, "Value of r: %p\n", r);
        graph->rowPointer[i] = &r;
        fprintf(stdout, "Value of graph->rowPointer[%d]: %p\n", i, graph->rowPointer[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < noOfVertices; j++){
            Row* row = graph->rowPointer[i];
            fprintf(stdout, "Value of row: %p\n", row);
            row[j]->vertex = 0;
            fprintf(stdout, "Value of row[%d]->vertex: %d\n", j, row[j]->vertex);
        }
    }

    return graph;
}
```

However my **OUTPUT** is -

> Value of graph->rowPointer: 003E3C50 
>  Value of r: 003E3C70  Value of graph->rowPointer[0]: 0028FEDC 
>  Value of r: 003E3C90
>   
>  Value of graph->rowPointer[1]: 0028FEDC 
>  Value of r:
>   003E3CB0 
>  Value of graph->rowPointer[2]: 0028FEDC 
>  Value
>   of r: 003E3CD0 
>  Value of graph->rowPointer[3]: 0028FEDC 
>   Value of r: 003E3CF0 
>  Value of graph->rowPointer[4]: 0028FEDC
>   
>  Value of row: 0028FEDC 
>  Value of row[0]->vertex: 0 
>   Value of row: 0028FEDC 
>  Value of row[1]->vertex: 0 
>  Value
>   of row: 0028FEDC 
>  Value of row[2]->vertex: 0 
>  Value of
>   row: 0028FEDC

and after this the code goes in infinite loop.

Thus there seems to be a problem when I assign `graph->rowPointer[i] = &r;`, why is this?
I think that I have allocated the pointers properly. Can someone tell me what is wrong?
**Thanks!**

Comment: `Row` is a pointer type?! What a confusing naming scheme!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r` in your code is a pointer to a `Node` that you allocated dynamically in a segment of the memory called the *heap*. The *heap* segment contains all the data for which you allocated space via the malloc-family. The data in that segment in persistant, and that's why you need to free it yourself with `free(void *)`.

Note that `r` **points** to somewhere in the `heap` segment where your data exists. The `r` variable itself is in the *stack* segment, which contains all the usual variables you declare, like `i` and `j`. Since the `r` variable is declared inside the `for` loop, **its scope is limited to that loop**. That means that `&r` will point to somewhere in the *stack* where the `r` variable is, but `r` will get removed at the end of the loop. You can't use `&r` because `r` won't exist outside of the loop.

You don't need to use `Node_t **` here. You can just store the address of the allocated memory and then fetch the address in the for loop as a pointer and use it as usual. Maybe the `typedef Node_t *Row;` isn't helping, you shouldn't use them for that kind of thing. As NPE pointed out, you have too many pointer levels for this.

Your .h should look like this :

```
struct node_t{
    int vertex;
};

struct graph_t{
    int noOfVertices;
    node_t *rowPointer;
};
```

You need to do some minor changes like these :

```
graph->rowPointer = (node_t *)malloc(noOfVertices * sizeof(node_t));
graph_p *graph = malloc(sizeof(graph_t));
```

Now you have to use `node_t *` instead of `Row`. Just store the address directly like that :

```
node_t *r = malloc(noOfVertices * sizeof(node_t));
graph->rowPointer[i] = r;
```

Just rewrite some lines to use a `node_t *` instead of a `node_t **`.

**EDIT :**
The rest of your header is really bad to be honest. You shouldn't use that much typedefs. And also the structures should not begin with capital letters. Changed the .h.

**EDIT 2 :**
Also the `node_t` struct here is pointless, since it only contains an `int`. This is where you want to use a `typedef`, so instead of making that struct, just do a `typedef int node;`

Answer (score 6):

You are quite right thinking that

```
    graph->rowPointer[i] = &r;
```

is problematic. You are taking (and keeping) the address of an automatic variable. The variable goes out of scope the moment you exit the block, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

To my eye, you have one too many levels of pointers in `rowPointer`. One is enough.

Comment: Can you suggest some alternative?

Comment: @VishalYadav: You need to allocate them dynamically.  You're filling up your return value with the addresses of variables which will go out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: @VishalYadav: Turn on the compiler's warnings and listen to them.

Answer (score 2):

`r` is a local variable, and `&r` is its address. `r` is a pointer, but `&r` is a different pointer: `&r` points to `r`, not to what `r` points to.

You've successfully assigned `r` to point to dynamically-allocated memory; to use it, just change `= &r` to `= r`.

Comment: I did that, but now the problem seems to be with `row[j]->vertex = 0;`. It again goes into an infinte loop.